Failed to create extension for Vertex AI
When I tried to create a vertex ai plugin from GCP console, it always failed with below error message:

Failed to create extension
Error message: 'List of found errors: 1.Field: extension.manifest.auth_config.api_key_config.api_key_secret; Message: Invalid Secret Manager SecretVersion resource name. '
Status: 400 Error code: 400
Tracking number: XXXXXXXXXXXX

I chose the API Key approach for auth configuration and somehow it always fails when I click the "CREATE EXTENSION" button. Do I need some additional permission here?

Got it. The value of the key should be a path points to a secrete in GCP's secret manager. It should look like below example:

"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/secrets/{SECRET_ID}/versions/1"

